Typeorm PostgreSQL schema acts like not existing even it exists
I have a database in postgres with different schemas. I want to use schema named g which contains my tables, see:

This is what app module looks like:
...
TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
  imports : [ConfigModule],
  useFactory: (configService: ConfigService): TypeOrmModuleOptions => configService.get('db'),
  inject: [ConfigService],
}),
...

Then TypeOrmModuleOptions:
export default registerAs('db', (): TypeOrmModuleOptions => ({
    type: "postgres",
    host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
    port: parseInt(process.env.DATABASE_PORT) || 5432,
    username: process.env.DATABASE_USER,
    password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
    name: process.env.DATABASE_NAME,
    entities: [Patient, Doctor],
    synchronize:  !!process.env.OPTIONS_SYNCHRONIZE || true,
    logging: !!process.env.OPTIONS_LOGGING || true,
})

Entity:
import { Entity,  Column, PrimaryColumn } from "typeorm";

@Entity({name: "patients", schema: "g"})
export class Patient {
@PrimaryColumn({name: "id_patient"})
id: number;

@Column({name: "pat_surname"})
surname: string;

@Column({name: "pat_name"})
name: string;

@Column({name: "pat_insu_num"})
insurance_number: string;

@Column({name: "pat_birth_date"})
birth_date: Date;

@Column({name: "id_inco"})
insurance_company_code: string;

@Column({name: "pat_gender"})
gender: number;

@Column({name: "pat_phone"})
phone: string;

@Column({name: "pat_email"})
email: string;

@Column({name: "pat_street"})
street: string;

@Column({name: "pat_city"})
city: string;

@Column({name: "pat_zip_code"})
zip: string;

@Column({name: "pat_country"})
country: string;

@Column({name: "pat_result_to_email"})
result_to_email: boolean;

@Column({name: "pat_patient_id"})
patient_id: number;

@Column({name: "ts_change", type: "timestamp"})
updated_at: Date;}

And finally service
...
async getAllPatients(limit: number, page: number): Promise<Patient[]> {
    const pat = new Patient;
    return await this.patientRepository
        .createQueryBuilder()
        .select()
        .offset((page-1)*limit)
        .limit(limit)
        .getRawMany() as Patient[];
}
...

after running application it says schema g does not exist. Here is error log:

Can anybody tell how can I set that schema to be used? I tried directly in TypeOrmModuleOptions, but result was same as well as when i used entity name as "g.patients".
